# Change Datatables Colvis Style

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, datatables

i am newbie to jquerymobile, css and datatables:).
i need to change datatables Colvis button & list style.

http://stokkers.mobi/jqm/tableview/demo.html is a very good example for me. it uses (+) icon instead of "Show /hide colum" text and to select columns opens a popup with jquerymobile style checkbox controlgroup. i created datatables with below code so couldn't copy/paste this link:)

Also i don't want to edit jquerymobile's javascript or css files to upgrade easily further releases.

realize that there is a need for responsive tableGrid plugin in jquerymobile environment. i think Datatables can achieve this..

Thank you for your help

```
$('#dynamicDatatableDIV').html( '<table id="dynamicDatatable" class="tbl_basket_style"></table>' );               
$('#dynamicDatatable').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'frCtip', //ColVis  'frtCipl'        
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [ "copy", "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]                       
    },
    //"bStateSave": true,//length, filtering, pagination and sorting not change when refresh(cooki)
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",        
    "iDisplayLength": 65536,
    "oColVis": {
        //"buttonText": "Show / Hide columns",
        "bRestore": true,
        "sAlign": "right"
    },        
    "aaData": aDataSet,        
    "aoColumns": aColumnData  
} );
```

Comment: not sure what you are asking, but i also did a jqm datatables version. pretty much the same as my example you are linking to, only run from a (customized) datatables version. haven't posted anything on it, but i once put a lengthy example here on stack overflow. let me see if i can dig up the link.

Comment: Sorry it's working on localhost now. in your example, there is (+) icon to choose visible columns. it opens a popup with checkboxes looks like standard jquery mobile screen. i want to apply same but don't want to modify jquerymobile css/js files. This link have an example to alternative style but isn't jquerymobile style. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/style.html

Comment: i haven't made any changes to jqm/css to do the menue. it's just a jqm custom select i'm populating with column headers to show/hide them. check this [link](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/) on responsive table design. i have mine following maggie wachs example, but using jqm with it